# How to pass image object to drawImage in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas, drawimage

I am trying to learn HTML5 and want to do the following:

1. Drag and copy the image to canvas
2. Drag and drop the image again inside that canvas.

I am trying to do this with JQuery and able to do drag and copy the image. I am not able to drag the image inside canvas.

I have checked so many examples and solutions on stackoverflow but everywhere it is for the image which is already present in the canvas. Is there any way to pass the image object in drawImage method on mousemove event in jquery?

I tried to follow the following example: `http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/QZejF/5/`

but like others, this one also has images already in the canvas.

I am cloning my image with the following code:

```
$("#img1").draggable({
    helper:'clone',
});
```

and inside canvas.droppable, i am doing this:

```
function dragDrop(e,ui){
    var x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX);
    var y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);
    ctx.drawImage(img1,x-1,y);
}
```

This same image i want to drag and drop inside the canvas again. Please help!! I have spent 5 hours but still unable to solve this.

Comment: The duplicate shows how to drag with an img element and drop it to be `drawImage`'ed on the canvas -- multiple times if desired. Ignore the squiggly line bits that are part of the original answer but you won't need.

Comment: thanks for the link but I want to drag the images in the same canvas. The link didn't help much. @markE

Comment: This duplicate answers how to drag-drop your img elements onto the canvas. There are many, many, many, many examples of how to drag an image around the canvas. [Here's one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304613/drag-image-after-dropping-it-in-canvas-element/22307860#22307860).